# How to organize Goose and Duck for a Dinner?

Tags: oven, duck, goose

I have goose and ducks leg and like to prepare them together in the oven.

I checked these two recipes [one](https://www.farmison.com/community/recipe/cook-goose-legs) and [two](https://bibleoftaste.com/2020/10/06/duck-leg-recipe/) and they seemed to be quite fitting.

Now my questions is :  one calls for oven heat of 135C  for the goose and   170Cfor the duck.

Can I just cook the duck at the 135C, since I want to have them both ready at the same time and I only have one oven.

It is my any hints on how to organize this would be great.

Comment: Have you tried looking at other recipes? You are likely to find a pair with closer temperatures although the timings will be different.

Comment: Do you need two different preparations?

Comment: Are you playing "[duck, duck, goose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck,_duck,_goose)"?

Comment: When I read the question, I was expecting a question regarding seating arrangements for feathered dinner guests.

Answer (score 1):

At my household, we used to roast duck whole, and it took many hours. Nowadays, we split our duck in half before placing it in the oven, which obviously takes less time to cook.

You can use 135C on your oven to roast the goose legs, alongside the duck legs each sliced into a certain number of pieces, depending on how long it's going to roast in the oven.

Comment: I think the OP is specifically referring to leg/thigh portions.

Answer (score -1):

How about cooking it in 80C and roast under the broiler? Idk if this is good idea, but I cook pork in 80C for hours and it comes out perfect. My theory is, that water is not able to turn into the steam and escape, so it should work for any type of meat. Am I right?

Comment: Water will evaporate and escape at 80°C, and it will have a long time to do so as cooking will be very slow.  It might be possible by sous vide, if you've got a big enough setup, but it's not clear whether that's what you mean, how long it would take, or whether the OP could do something like that.

Comment: @ChrisH I cook 1,5 kg (5 lb) pork at this temp for like 2 hours, so I'd expect it to be ready in IDK like 1h.
OP's situation seem to be irrelevant since it was posted some time ago and this post would give birth already. Just asking for science.